# Google Sheets calculation methodology through scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am working with a large Google Sheet file. It has 10 sheets, each large with many sumproducts on them. Is there a way to "turn off" and "turn on" the calculation of the spreadsheet from inside a script function. I do a lot of single cell updating and don't need all the sheets to recalculate. I am assuming Google Sheets is recalculating all associated cells everything every time I update a cell. (I think I am looking for the opposite of .flush(), but not sure)

Also: if anyone knows of a good book that goes over Googles Sheets permissible Script commands, with examples, please let me know.

Comment: Have you searched the official documentation? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Don't think you can turn off default calculations. See best practices in the official documentation.